# Simulink: Real-Time Cross Correlation

Tags: signals, real-time, simulink, cross-correlation, discretization

I am working on a project, it's complicated to explain fully but it goes as follows:

We have 2 signals A and B, where B is a time delayed echo of A. I want to use Real-Time Cross Correlation to show that the time delay will remain constant while the medium through which the signals are travelling does not change.

Issues arise due to my lack of experience with both Simulink and Communications Statistics etc..

So how do I go about this? I have two continuous signals A and B, and I believe what I have to do is convert them to discrete signals and then use frame based processing and XCORR... but I just don't know how to go about that.

Can anyone help? Or even provide an example of how to cross correlate two continuous signals/an example on how to use XCORR and frame based processing?

Comment: **Update!** I've had someone explain to me how buffering works, so now I have the frames and I want to find the time delay between the two channels

Answer (score 0):

Since a month passed by since your question I assume you probably already found the answer.

I can explain how it should work in a script. xcorr is the function mainly used, with the first 2 inputs being signal A and B. Optionally you can add a third parameter to define correlation interval. If you buffer your signals this is pointless as you can just choose an appropriate buffer size instead that'll be used. If you just casually plot the result of a discrete correlation the delay will be given in terms of samples, you can get the true delay value from the difference of the peak value and the zero-lag (assuming there isn't a terribly high amount of noise that would corrupt the result).